# How to post a new message on the IBM watson work services?

Tags: rest, watson

I'm trying to post with POSTMAN to the new IBM Watson work services but only get one error after the other.

This documentation does not clearly explain the body scheme for messages (or does it?):

```
https://workspace.ibm.com/developer/docs#genericannotation
```

So I'm guessing around:
POST to

```
https://api.watsonwork.ibm.com/v1/spaces/{spaceId}/messages
```

With headers:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Basic 123456789
spaceId: MySpaceID
body:{"input": {"text": "Hello"}}
```

What's the right scheme for the body to post that message with success?

I always get the following error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-10-27T12:53:07.134+0000",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/teams/{spaceId}/messages"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a Script on GitHub, you can have more details on file [PostMessageOnWatsonWorkspace.py](https://github.com/ebasso/rest-client-examples/tree/master/ibm-watson-work)

I put part of the code below

````
appname = 'PostMessageOnWatsonWorkspace'

text = """
Visit [IBM site](http://www.ibm.com), and leave a *message*.

Have _fun_!!!

Code Line:
`code`

Code Block:
```
code block
```
Bye
"""
````

Currently to format has only **Bold**, *Italic*, Code and links.

And this is an example of Post data.

```
data = {
  'type': 'appMessage',
  'version': 1.0,
  'annotations': [{
    'type': 'generic',
    'version': 1.0,
    'color': '#4FC3F7',
    'title': appname + ' --> sendRichMessage at ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()),
    'text': text,
    'actor': {
      'name': 'Enio Basso',
      'avatar': '',
      'url': 'https://ebasso.net'
    }
  }]
}
```

Other details you can find on [documentation](https://developer.watsonwork.ibm.com/docs).